# Shapeless' Lazy and implicit parameter

Tags: scala, parameters, implicit, shapeless

I am trying to trace the sequence of construction (lots of println) and have this code
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4DRXuhUZS8mN551eI7vN3Q

```
import shapeless._
object abc {
  sealed trait List[+T]
  case class Cons[T](hd: T, tl: List[T]) extends List[T]
  sealed trait Nil extends List[Nothing]
  case object Nil extends Nil

  trait Show[T] {
    def apply(t: T): String
  }

  object Show {
    // Base case for Int
    implicit def showInt: Show[Int] = new Show[Int] {
      println("222")
      def apply(t: Int) = t.toString
      println("222 end")
    }
    // Base case for Nil
    implicit def showNil: Show[Nil] = new Show[Nil] {
      def apply(t: Nil) = "Nil"
    }
    
    // without Lazy, resoving sc requires resolving sl, which in turn sc -- infinite looping
    // Lazy stops this looping and saying I got this, so go on to resolve showCons using proxy st and sl. real st and sl can be accessed using st.value and sl.value
    // which will lazily resolved.
    // Case for Cons[T]: note (mutually) recursive implicit argument referencing Show[List[T]]
    implicit def showCons[T](implicit st: Lazy[Show[T]], sl: Lazy[Show[List[T]]]): Show[Cons[T]] = { 
      val t = new Show[Cons[T]] {
      println(" 111")
      def apply(t: Cons[T]) = {
          println("     apply 111 ")
          println(s"      try to show ${t.tl}")
          val sss = s"Cons(${show(t.hd)(st.value)}, ${show(t.tl)(sl.value)})"
          println("     apply 111 end ")
          sss
      }
      println(" 111 end") // the reason 111 comes before 333 at the beginning is determined by internal algorithm of Lazy
      }
      t
    }
    // Case for List[T]: note (mutually) recursive implicit argument referencing Show[Cons[T]]
    implicit def showList[T](implicit sc: Lazy[Show[Cons[T]]]): Show[List[T]] = new Show[List[T]] {
      println(" 333")
      def apply(t: List[T]) = t match {
        case n: Nil => show(n)
        case c: Cons[T] => { 
          println("  apply 333")
          val tmp = show(c)(sc.value) //explicitly passing down parameter
          println("  apply 333 end") 
          tmp
        }
      }
      println(" 333 end")
    }
  }

  def show[T](t: T)(implicit s: Show[T]) = s(t)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val l: List[Int] = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))
    println(show(l))
  }
}
```

and when I run it, it prints out

```
 111
 111 end
 333
 333 end
  apply 333
     apply 111 
      try to show Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil))
222
222 end
 333
 333 end
  apply 333
     apply 111 
      try to show Cons(3,Nil)
  apply 333
     apply 111 
      try to show Nil
     apply 111 end 
  apply 333 end
     apply 111 end 
  apply 333 end
     apply 111 end 
  apply 333 end
Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))
```

why `111` and `111 end` got executed (constructed) before `333` and `333 end` even though `implicit sc: Lazy[Show[Cons[T]]]` has `Lazy` in it? Shouldn't it be delayed till `sc.value` got referenced?
I can see that `st` and `sl` are lazily constructed, but wondering why `sc` is immediately constructed? Does Lazy algorithm thinks that it is ok to construct `sc` without causing an infinite loop issue?

Comment: `shapeless.Lazy` is not about lazy evaluation, it's about relaxing detecting "diverging implicit expansion" by compiler.

Comment: "without Lazy, resoving sc requires resolving sl, which in turn sc -- infinite looping" This is not true either. For example for `Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))` looping is 3 times (and not infinite). `Lazy` is not about avoiding infinite looping, it's about relaxing detecting "diverging implicit expansion" by compiler.

Comment: See also by-name implicits in 2.13 https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0 https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/byname-implicits.html https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6050 https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7368